# web font letter space huge on ios

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, safari, webfonts

Font "DIN Condensed" letter spacing on ios is huge (exactly one previous letter width extra). This happens with all browsers (Safari and Google) on all ios devices, with original ttf, and with font-squirrel generated woff as well.

How can I fix this?

(Tried so far as well - renaming font-file to .otf)

This is the site: https://itstestlab.eu/

[image: sample of font letter spacing on ios]

Comment: maybe the font is like that?

Comment: No, it isn't - on desktop and Android it shows normally spaced, added site link to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Included web version from Typekit CDN and it works from there.

Seems that this is some kind of a copy protection system. The original file client sent to me was for desktop use only.

Answer (score 1):

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontName';src:url('/f/f.woff2') format('woff2'),url('/f/f.woff') format('woff')}
```

This is the closest I got to importing fonts and having no issues with Chrome, Firefox, IE10, Edge, Safari back to version 5 upwards and iPhone 5S with original iOS, upwards.
It also solved Apple's DRM (copyright protection) issues  with other font formats.

I use FontSquirrel to convert fonts into other formats, and also "normalize" them, inlcuding mis-sized, mis-defined glyphs. There are a lot of options, but going the pre-defined "usual" conversion should work.

EDIT: I have looked into your CSS and found that the last rule of /cms/css/cms_normalise.scss applies some non-standard stuff to your fonts. It looks like an overklill of a reset.css. I am not sure if that causes the problem, since I am unable to reproduce it, but you might want to check it out..

Comment: text-size-adjust: 100%; - this is to not let iphones to make fonts bigger. There are weird bugs related to this, where texts, defined the same font-size, are displayed differently, dependent of location in dom.